# What dishware material is microwave safe and also kasherable?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

I'm confused by some of the rabbinical advisory websites regarding what dishware can be kashered.  Evidently glass and ceramic, the most convenient microwave safe materials, according to Askkenasi cannot be kashered and therefore can't be used for kosher service.  Are there ANY microwave-safe materials for dishes which CAN be kashered?

Comment: Can you not use microwave-safe plastics that may not be kashered but are often just disposed of. Hermolis seems to get by fine through using them.

Comment: That would be wasteful, and consume money I don't have.

Comment: Give them away to non-Jews afterwards then. But they are cheap.

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/msh210-1532532172 may help.

Comment: If you're buying something new, it doesn't need to be kashered (cf your other question)

Comment: As I just found out.

Answer (score 1):

For plates and soup bowls, the most convenient articles would be those of plain (without ornamentation) steel or aluminum.

#### Background

It is a commonly believed myth that no metal items can be safely used in a microwave oven. A clear indication of this assumption's falsity is the fact that the insides of the appliance are metal, and some ovens even have metal turntables or racks:

[image: A microwave oven with its metal shelf[1]]

The truth is that smooth metal objects are perfectly safe in microwave ovens, however the food to heat slower if extensively covered. Therefore, smooth plates and open bowls are kasherable microwavable dishware.

#### Warning

Do not attempt to use any non-smooth metal object in a microwave, such as torn or crumbled aluminum foil, aluminum trays, ornamented plates, forks, serrated knives, etc. Doing so may cause arcing, property damage, and injury!

Comment: The average person is wary to use metal in a microwave.  Although in some cases it should be fine see: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_oven#Hazards most people don't seem to want to knowingly put any metal in there.

Comment: I don't know the OP. But in general this would make a better answer by dispelling myths and providing the information people are lacking. I know what what you were alluding to by writing without ornamentation, but even that is misleading as someone might think their plain fork is safe to put in.

Comment: Perfect:) +1. Addressed the issue. Dispelled the myth. Warned against dangerous confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Wood containers.
Bone containers.
Stone containers.
(According to some opinions glass containers).
(I guess also leather is kosherabe)

The above is If kashered means to be able to use it after it was used for not kosher

Comment: what is your source?

Comment: @Dude For what that it is kosherabe or microwavable?